# Инициализация класса по умолчанию стандартным конструктором

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация

Можно решить, что стандартный конструктор инициализирует встроенные типы значениями 0.

```
class A
{
public:
    int val;
    char *pnt;
};

int main (void)
{
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    cout << (void *) a.pnt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
0  
0x0
```

Но, при добавлении массива, пропадает инициализация 0 вовсе.

```
class A
{
public:
    int val;
    char *pnt;
    int arr[10];
};

int main (void)
{
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    cout << (void *) a.pnt << endl;

    for(auto &it: a.arr)
        cout << it << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
-519304344
0x10eb3f000
-519304320 32766 -519304344 32766 259249440 1 0 1 259248712 1
```

Как объяснить такое поведение инициализации по умолчанию? В каких случаях инициализация происходит гарантированно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить на основании первого эксперимента, что конструктор по-умолчанию инициализирует поля 0, нельзя. Как и в первом, так и во втором случае переменные никак не инициализируются, и обращаясь к ним вы получаете неопределенное поведение.

Его можно избежать, используя синтаксис [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
A a{}; // теперь все действительно инициализировано 0
cout << a.val << endl;
cout << (void *) a.pnt << endl;
```

Comment: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    A a{};

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка компиляции?

Comment: @Vitaly [Никакой ошибки не возникает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UqdX4peDWC5RFicm).

Comment: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38). Ошибка однозначно возникает у меня. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Vitaly Может clang-900 (откуда такие цифры? сейчас 6 самая свежая) собирает по-умолчанию с опцией `--std=c++98`? Используйте `--std=c++17` или хотя бы `--std=c++11`.

Comment: спасибо, помогло --std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @VTT

Помимо `list initialization` есть понятие [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) которое также будет инициализировать всегда члены класса вызывая их соответсвующие конструкторы по умолчанию

```
A a = A();
cout << a.val << endl;
cout << (void *) a.pnt << endl;
```

а вот это:

`A a;`

называется [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) которое никак не обязано инициализировать члены класса по стандарту.